# User input using this Scanner class in JAVA

Tags: java

So I have this program that is supposed to take user input like car names and calculate prices and payment per month right here:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NewCar
{

private int year;
private String make;
private String model;
private double sticker,discount,tax,finalP,final2,final3;
private int month,monPayt;
private int abbrev1;
private String abbrev2;
private String abbrev3;

   public NewCar(int year, String make, String model)
   {
      this.year= year;
      this.make= make;
      this.model = model;
   }

   public int getYear()
   {
      return year;
   }

   public String getMake()
   {
      return make;
   }

   public String getModel()
   {
      return model;
   }

   public String carDesc()
   {
      return year + " " + make + " "  + model;
   }

   public String carAbbrev()
   {
      abbrev1 = year % 100;
      String abbrev2 = make.substring(0,1);
      String abbrev3 = model.substring(0,1);
      return abbrev1 + abbrev2 + abbrev3;
   }


   public double calcFinalPrice()
   {
      final2 = (sticker - discount);
      final3 = final2 * tax;
      finalP = final2 + final3;
      return finalP;
   }

   public int calcZeroPctMonPayt()
   {
      monPayt = (int)finalP / month;
      return monPayt;
   }


   public String toString()
   {
      return "You want to purchase a " + carDesc() + ". Abbreviation: " + carAbbrev();
   }


}
```

And i test it with this tester class:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NewCarTester
{





   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the car's Year, Make and Model: ");
      int year = scan.nextInt();
      String make = scan.next();
      String model = scan.next();

      System.out.println("Enter the Sticker Price: ");
      int sticker = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter the discount: ");
      int discount = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter the Sales Tax Rate: ");
      int tax = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter the number of Months at Zero Percent Interest: ");
      int month = scan.nextInt();

      NewCar c = new NewCar(year, make, model);

      System.out.println(c.toString());
      System.out.println("Final Price : " + c.calcFinalPrice());
      System.out.println(c.calcZeroPctMonPayt());





    }
}
```

Now everything works fine accept the calcualtion methods, Whenever i call one of the calculation methods i get 0.0 everytime. This leads me to believe that the inputs the user is putting in are not correctly getting stored into the variables which they are supposed to go into. Can anyone identify the problem and help me fix it? Thanks! Also, one more problem im having is that if a user enters the sales tax with a decimal in it, the program gets an error and stops running, anyone have any insight on that?

Comment: On top of what I see in the answers so far, you probably want `(int) (finalP/month)` instead of `(int) finalP/ month` in `calcZeroPctMonPayt()`. If I recall correctly, the latter casts `finalP` to an `int` *then* does the division.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely. the variabkle used in  `calcFinalPrice(`) method i.e.

```
  final2 = (sticker- discount);

  final3 = final2 * tax;

  finalP = final2 + final3;

  return finalP;
```

All the variable used above get default value at the time of object creation based on their data type.

Modify your constructor as below and you should get the calculated final price.

```
public NewCar(int year, String make, String model,int sticker,int discount,int tax,int month)
  {      
    this.year= year;
    this.make= make;
    this.model = model;
    this.sticker=sticker;
    this.discount=discount;
    this.tax=tax;
    this.month=month;
}
```

Comment: remove the start from start and end of constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the arguments as discount , tax rate etc pass them like following by default the are being assigned zero. Use the following code it will solve your problem

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NewCar
{

private int year;
private String make;
private String model;
private double sticker,discount,tax,finalP,final2,final3;
private int month,monPayt;
private int abbrev1;
private String abbrev2;
private String abbrev3;

   public NewCar(int year, String make, String model,double sticker,double discount,double tax,int month)
   {
      this.year= year;
      this.make= make;
      this.model = model;
      this.sticker=sticker;
      this.discount=discount;
      this.tax=tax;
      this.month=month;
   }

   public int getYear()
   {
      return year;
   }

   public String getMake()
   {
      return make;
   }

   public String getModel()
   {
      return model;
   }

   public String carDesc()
   {
      return year + " " + make + " "  + model;
   }

   public String carAbbrev()
   {
      abbrev1 = year % 100;
      String abbrev2 = make.substring(0,1);
      String abbrev3 = model.substring(0,1);
      return abbrev1 + abbrev2 + abbrev3;
   }


   public double calcFinalPrice()
   {
      final2 = (sticker - discount);
      final3 = final2 * tax;
      finalP = final2 + final3;
      return finalP;
   }

   public int calcZeroPctMonPayt()
   {
      monPayt = (int)finalP / month;
      return monPayt;
   }


   public String toString()
   {
      return "You want to purchase a " + carDesc() + ". Abbreviation: " + carAbbrev();
   }


}






 class NewCarTester
{





   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the car's Year, Make and Model: ");
      int year = scan.nextInt();
      String make = scan.next();
      String model = scan.next();

      System.out.println("Enter the Sticker Price: ");
      int sticker = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter the discount: ");
      int discount = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter the Sales Tax Rate: ");
      int tax = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter the number of Months at Zero Percent Interest: ");
      int month = scan.nextInt();

      NewCar c = new NewCar(year, make, model,sticker,discount,tax,month);

      System.out.println(c.toString());
      System.out.println("Final Price : " + c.calcFinalPrice());
      System.out.println(c.calcZeroPctMonPayt());





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anywhere in your test where you are setting the Tax, discount etc... to the NewCar object.

You must follow the get and set object oriented approach for each of your public properties

```
public double getTax()
{
   return tax;
}

public void setTax(double taxVal)
{
    this.tax = taxVal;
}
```

Then in your created object you can do something like:

```
NewCar c = new NewCar(year, make, model);
c.setTax(5.00);
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

You never actually supply values for `sticker`, `discount` or `tax` to the instance of `NewCar`, making `0` by default.

You need to supply some way to supply the values you get from the user to this class

Perhaps via the constructor, the same way you've set `year`, `make` and `model` or via setter methods, for example...

```
public void setSticker(double sticker) {
    this.sticker = sticker;
}
```